# How do I keep functions/variables local to my zshrc?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

Any variable that I declare in my `zshrc` is available in the shell as an environment variable. I don't want this to happen.

I tried putting the variables in a function and setting them as local, but then the function is available outside of the `zshrc`.

How can I make it so *what happens in my zshrc stays in my zshrc*?

Comment: Careful, there is more to this story than initially appears. I invite you to check my answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

They are available, but they are not exported so scripts launching from command-line don’t get these variables. If your `.zshrc` looks like

```
function zshrc()
{
    local VAR=1
    # Do stuff
}
zshrc
```

and you then never want to launch `zshrc` function again you can just do

```
unfunction zshrc
```

afterwards.

Comment: It's preferable to use an anonymous function, as in qqx's answer. Then you do not need the `unfunction`.

Answer (score 57):

If you're using a recent version of zsh you can use an anonymous function:

```
function () {
  local xyz=abc
  # whatever
}
```

The function will be automatically executed and then thrown away, it exists only for scoping purposes.

This works for *any sourced file*, not only zshrc.

Comment: That covers variables, but how can you declare a local function?

Answer (score 17):

If you do not prefix a variable with the word `local` it will remain until you do one of the following:

1. Open a new terminal window.
2. Run `exec zsh` or `exec bash` depending on your shell. This just clears out your local variables that were not assigned with the word `local`.

#### Avoid this

```
method_name(){
  a=11
  echo $a
}
```

#### Correct Example

```
method_name(){
  local a=11
  echo $a
}
```

This variable is scoped to the function name `method_name` and only available inside of the function when called (and not afterwards).

#### If you want direct access to that local variable you can set it this way

`local z=11`

#### And call it this way

`echo $z`

## Additionally, environment variables are different from local variables

Depending on your shell and needs, you may use `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` etc. to store functions and aliases.

[View this reference for more on environment variables and their respective shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables)

[Also read this to understand how to set environment variables on the command line using shell expansions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56444/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-command-line-and-have-it-appear-in-c)

You can quickly view environment variables with `env` or `printenv`

The convention is to use UPPERCASE

#### To temporarily set an environment variable (stored until you close the terminal)

`export A=11` or  `export B="11 is part of this string"`

Assuming you have opened a new terminal window or sourced .zshrc or .bashrc or whichever you are using you can now use this environment variable until you close your terminal session. Note: do not use $ when setting, but do use $ when referencing the variable.

#### Examples

`echo "A is equal to: $A and that is pretty nice"`

`echo "$A"`

## How to source a file

`source ~/path/to/file/filename`

#### Example

`source ~/.bash_profile`

#### To set an environment variable (until you remove it or set it again)

Use the code above but place it in your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc or other respective file. Save the file and source it.

#### Example

`export B="11 is part of this string"`

#### You now can view it with

`env`

To remove that environment variable, remove it from the file and again source the file.

## To temporarily remove an environmental variable, use unset

#### Example

`unset B`

Note there is no `$` when unsetting.

#### To set environment variables from the command line

`export BLABLA="environment variable set from the command line, saved in file for later use"`

Check the file you are sending it to, it may not start on a new line, it might have been concatenated to your last line which was some other function, alias or other.

This is not a fully comprehensive answer, but it is a great step in the right direction. It shows how scope in a terminal shell can be set, used and removed.

Comment: While correct, this isn't helpful in answering OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

There is apparently a bash convention to name 'private' functions with double underscore .. of course they are not actually private . I am using this convention in my .zshrc.

```
function __comment()
{
  curr=`pwd`
  echo "$curr $*"
}

__comment 'Here is a Comment'
```

Comment: I'm guessing the convention of double underscore is for system or library names to prevent conflict with the user's (your) own functions. So that's why you should be using a single underscore for your own private functions or you'd be defeating the purpose of their using the double underscore.